# Transforming 5 xml files about products into one file

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, xslt-2.0

I have a little problem with this task. My main goal is to transform 5 different files into one big xml file. The main structure is: root = catalog, with a lot of product elements inside. I managed to copy all the product elements inside one catalog element, and add an attribute to the product tag containing the ref element's value. But, I can't figure out how to merge the product elements with the same id/ref value. Each source xml has information about the same products, and I would like to have all data inside one product element each, not speparate product elements with same attributes. Could you help me with these? Here are some examples:
File1:

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <ref>2008</ref>
        <name>Nwovenband</name>
        <type>Hoedenband</type>
        <composition>Non-Woven</composition>
        <otherinfo/>
        <extendedinfo>Non-woven lint voor hoed, in verschillende kleuren. In de maat
            67x2,7cm.</extendedinfo>
        <brand/>
        <printcode/>
        <item_long>67</item_long>
        <item_hight>2.7</item_hight>
        <item_width/>
        <item_diameter/>
        <item_weight>2</item_weight>
        <masterbox_long/>
        <masterbox_hight/>
        <masterbox_width/>
        <masterbox_weight/>
        <masterbox_units>0</masterbox_units>
        <palet_units>104000</palet_units>
        <palet_boxs>42</palet_boxs>
        <palet_weight>580</palet_weight>
        <categories>
            <category_ref_1>27</category_ref_1>
            <category_name_1>HOEDEN EN PETTEN </category_name_1>
            <category_ref_2/>
            <category_name_2/>
            <category_ref_3/>
            <category_name_3/>
            <category_ref_4/>
            <category_name_4/>
            <category_ref_5/>
            <category_name_5/>
        </categories>
        <link360>http://etools.boxpromotions.com/videos/2008/360/output/2008.html</link360>
        <linkvideo/>
        <variants>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008005000</matnr>
                <refct>2008AMAS/T</refct>
                <colour>AMA</colour>
                <colftp>AMA</colftp>
                <colourname>GEEL</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008019000</matnr>
                <refct>2008AZULS/T</refct>
                <colour>AZUL</colour>
                <colftp>AZUL</colftp>
                <colourname>BLAUW</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008021000</matnr>
                <refct>2008AZCS/T</refct>
                <colour>AZC</colour>
                <colftp>AZC</colftp>
                <colourname>BLAUW LICHT</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008001000</matnr>
                <refct>2008BLAS/T</refct>
                <colour>BLA</colour>
                <colftp>BLA</colftp>
                <colourname>WIT</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008014000</matnr>
                <refct>2008KAKS/T</refct>
                <colour>KAK</colour>
                <colftp>KAK</colftp>
                <colourname>KAKI</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008006000</matnr>
                <refct>2008MARS/T</refct>
                <colour>MAR</colour>
                <colftp>MAR</colftp>
                <colourname>MARINO</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008007000</matnr>
                <refct>2008NARAS/T</refct>
                <colour>NARA</colour>
                <colftp>NARA</colftp>
                <colourname>ORANGE</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008002000</matnr>
                <refct>2008NEGS/T</refct>
                <colour>NEG</colour>
                <colftp>NEG</colftp>
                <colourname>ZWART</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008003000</matnr>
                <refct>2008ROJS/T</refct>
                <colour>ROJ</colour>
                <colftp>ROJ</colftp>
                <colourname>ROOD</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008004000</matnr>
                <refct>2008VERS/T</refct>
                <colour>VER</colour>
                <colftp>VER</colftp>
                <colourname>GROEN</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <matnr>12008227000</matnr>
                <refct>2008VEOS/T</refct>
                <colour>VEO</colour>
                <colftp>VEO</colftp>
                <colourname>DONKERGROEN</colourname>
                <size>S/T</size>
                
            </variant>
        </variants>
    </product>
    ...
</catalog>
```

File2:

```
<catalog>
    <date>23/10/2020</date>
    <product>
        <ref>2008</ref>
        <name>NWOVENBAND</name>
        <printjobs> </printjobs>
    </product>
    ...
</catalog>
```

Same goes for the other files.
I use this XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <!-- Keep indentation and delete empty lines. -->
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <!-- Copy everything into the result file. -->  
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Copy everything inside one <catalog> element into the result file. -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <catalog>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('alldatafile_hol.xml')/catalog/*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('allprintdatafile_hol.xml')/catalog/*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('allstockgroupedfile.xml')/catalog/*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('pricefile_€8016001.xml')/catalog/*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('PrintPrices_ing.xml')/*"/>
        </catalog>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Add a @prod_id attribute to each <product> element, with the value of the <ref> element. -->
    <xsl:template match="product">
        <product prod_id="{ref}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </product>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Delete the <ref> elements. -->
    <xsl:template match="ref"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is that from the different files the product elements with the same ref value still gets copied into separate product elements. I transform the ref element into a prod_id attribute of the product elements, but can't figure out how to merge the product elements with the same attribute! If anyone could help me I would be very grateful!

Comment: Use a key or grouping obviously.

Comment: You could use a for-each-group that selects the products from all 5 files at the same time and then output all the products/categories for each group.

Comment: The for-each-group seems a good idea, I tried to use something like this:
```<xsl:template match="catalog">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group  select="product" group-by="@prod_id">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>```
But it still doesn't give the desired results (sorry for the bad formatting). Should I rather include this grouping template in the main template which copies everything inside 1 catalog element?

Comment: It's easier to read if you post your code in your question. Try something like <xsl:for-each-group select="document('1.xml')/.../... | document('2.xml')/.../... | ........" group-by"...">